# FontAwesome icon showing as black box. What CSS is needed to display icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Pretty sure I am being dim but how do I get the icon to display? Is certain CSS needed and if so what would that be?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/krp0psdj/ check

Comment: If you test this file in local, you should put `http://`, it will resolve the case. Try to check in network tab to ensure that file exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work okay.

I suspect that you need to add the `http://` into your URL in `href`.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
```

### What is the cause of the problem?

Links to external resources with no scheme (`http:`) break when the page is loaded via the file system (`file://path/to/webpage`). The current scheme is maintained, and the page will be unable to find them:

```
This can't be found:
file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

To ensure that you can find external resources when loading a webpage from your file system, you should always include the scheme. CDN's will often omit the scheme, to reuse the current scheme to serve `http` resources on `http` sites and secure `https` resources on `https` sites.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have another font overriding your icon font. Search your CSS to see if there is another `font-family:OtherFont!important;`.

- Make sure that your Font-awesome CSS is loaded, and font-urls point to the correct fonts.
- Check that you have the correct classes i.e. `<i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>`
- Then explicitly specify your `i.fa` tags (which are used by Font-awesome to create the font) to

  `i.fa{ 
       font-family:FontAwesome!important; 
  }`

Worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

---

Have you included the font files? Check your console for any 404s/errors.

I just tried with the 'angle-double-down' class and it works.